# Pegando com preg_match e-mail com caracteres especiais PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

Com esse código abaixo ele não pega emails com underline.

É possivel modificar para ele pegar inclusive underline e demais caracteres especiais?

No exemplo abaixo ele retorna o valor "ca@hotmail.com" sendo que o correto seria "aline_ca@hotmail.com"

```
preg_match('/([-.a-zA-Z]{1,30})@([-.a-zA-Z]{1,30})([.]{1})([-.a-zA-Z]{1,10})/', 'asdas asdasd asdas aline_ca@hotmail.com asdasd asdas asdas', $msgPreg1);
    echo trim($msgPreg1[0]);
```

Comment: o intuito é extrair emails de um texto ou validar uma entrada (sanitizar, filtrar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta adicionar `_` no regex, outro detalhe é que quando usar hife dentro de `[]` faça o "escape", também recomendo adicionar `[0-9]` (ou \d) pois alguns emails tem numeros, ficaria assim:

Se quiser que tenha underline/underscore no "nome do usuário/conta":

```
/([_\-.a-zA-Z\d]{1,30})@([\-.a-zA-Z\d]{1,30})([.]{1})([\-.a-zA-Z]{1,10})/
```

O código ficaria assim:

```
preg_match('/([_\-.a-zA-Z\d]{1,30})@([\-.a-zA-Z\d]{1,30})([.]{1})([\-.a-zA-Z]{1,10})/', 'asdas asdasd asdas aline_ca@hotmail.com asdasd asdas asdas', $msgPreg1);
```

Se quiser que tenha underline/underscore no "nome do usuário/conta" e dominio:

```
/([_\-.a-zA-Z\d]{1,30})@([_\-.a-zA-Z\d]{1,30})([.]{1})([_\-.a-zA-Z]{1,10})/
```

O código ficaria assim:

```
preg_match('/([_\-.a-zA-Z\d]{1,30})@([_\-.a-zA-Z\d]{1,30})([.]{1})([_\-.a-zA-Z]{1,10})/', 'asdas asdasd asdas aline_ca@hotmail.com asdasd asdas asdas', $msgPreg1);
```

**Nota:** `preg_match` só vai lhe retornar um e-mail (1 match), para pegar mais de um use `preg_match_all`, veja a diferença no ideone:

- [preg_match](http://ideone.com/HHcBdE)
- [preg_match_all](http://ideone.com/DwUEJg)